# Adding Attribute to category in Magento.

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I know, we can add attribute to product list. 
I also know, we can add attribute to category using db query. Something like the link below.

http://miragedesign.net/newss/magento-add-custom-attributes-to-category/
My question, is not possible to do through magento admin, as we do for product list?

If yes, How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry there is no admin interface for linking of attributes to category
You can use setup script for that

http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: Thanks for your answer sandeep. Creating module is the worst thing anyone can do. rather than doing something simple.